# Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong/how to fix this shell script?

Tags: shell-script

What I want to achieve is if the name is "Instructor", it replies "Good Afternoon, Instructor", if any other name, it will reply "Good Evening, 'name' " and send the result to the file.txt file.

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p "what's your name?"

if [ "$name" = "Instructor" ]
then 
    echo "Good Afternoon, Instructor"
else
    echo "good Evening, "$name" >> file.txt
fi
```

Comment: And what's `$name`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not reading the name from the user, and you use `name` and then `NAME` (these are two different variables). Also, `$name` should be double quoted in the if-statement.

To read input from the user into the variable `name`, use `read`:

```
read name
```

With `bash`, you may also use `read` to display a custom prompt, if you so wish:

```
echo 'Hello!'
read -p "What's your name? > " name
```

If you *don't* give `read` the name of a variable, the text will go into a variable called `REPLY` by default.

Comment: Sorry I'm really new to shell scripting. I think I'm not properly understanding, but doesn't that just show "What's your name?" before asking for a reply?

Comment: @user218619 Yes, it will show `What's your name? > ` and then wait for user input. Put that before your if-statement.

Comment: and quote $name in the `if`/test line!

Comment: It seems like there's still an error as I can't run the script after putting the quotes on $name and the read statement. I'm still having trouble on the if statement.

Comment: @user218619 your last edit doesn't show that you're putting `name` at the end of the `read` statement...

Comment: also, resist the temptation to "fix" your question based on the answer -- that makes the answer look odd.

Comment: Oh, sorry about that. Even putting the name at the end of the read statement, I don't see any changes.

Comment: Okay, I finally got it to work! http://puu.sh/upHjJ.jpg 
Sorry for the trouble and thank you all!

Comment: @user218619 Rather than doubling up the `echo` to produce output both to the terminal and to a file, you may use `echo "Good Evening, $name" | tee -a file.txt`.